# jQuery - append/ remove tags to each item's list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve the `value` of **each** `.item` input as removable tags where more tags can be appended / removed from each item's `.tags` list.

The problem is that the 'value' data is populating for every '.tag' wrapper and not just for the individual item that the input is nested in.

How do I change the function so that it runs on each item?

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  // create stored tags
  var $data = $(this).find(".tags-area").attr("data-value");
  if ($data) {
    var $split = $data.split(" ");
    $.each($split, function(number) {
      $('<div class="tag-term"  />')
        .appendTo(".tags")
        .append($split[number])
        .append('<a class="close" href="#">x</a>');
    });
  }

  //create tag
  var tagged = function() {
    var $tag = $(".tags-area").val();
    if ($tag) {
      $('<div class="tag-term"  />')
        .appendTo(".tags")
        .append($tag)
        .append('<a class="close" href="#">x</a>');
      $(".tags-area").val("");
    }
  };

  //catch enter
  $(".tags-area").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      tagged();
    }
  });

  //remove tag
  $(".tags").on("click", ".tag-term a", function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .remove();
  });

  //remove tag backspace
  $(".tags-area").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
      var $caret = $(".tags-area").getCursorPosition();
      if ($caret === 0) {
        $(".tags .tag-term")
          .last()
          .remove();
      }
    }
  });

  //get caret position
  $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    var pos = 0;
    if ("selectionStart" in el) {
      pos = el.selectionStart;
    } else if ("selection" in document) {
      el.focus();
      var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
      var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
      Sel.moveStart("character", -el.value.length);
      pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
    }
    return pos;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="display:flex">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="tags"></div>
    <textarea placeholder="Add a tag..." class="tags-area" data-value="alpha beta gamma"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="tags"></div>
    <textarea placeholder="Add a tag..." class="tags-area" data-value="new two three"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Updated the question. The tags are iterating for all items but I only want the tags for each item to come from that items 'value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial data load:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    // create stored tags
    var $data = $(this).find(".tags-area").data("value");

    if ($data) {
        var tags = $(this).find(".tags");
        var $split = $data.split(" ");

        $.each($split, function(index) {
            $('<div class="tag-term" />')
                .appendTo(tags)
                .append($split[index])
                .append(' <a class="close" href="#">x</a>');
        });
    }
});
```

Then, this will add the tag to the `.tags` that are in the same `.item` as the `.tags-area`:

```
  //create tag
  var tagged = function(area) {
      var $tag = $(area).val();

      if ($tag) {
          var tags = $(area).parents('.item').find('.tags');
          $('<div class="tag-term" />')
              .appendTo(tags)
              .append($tag)
              .append(' <a class="close" href="#">x</a>');
          $(area).val("");
      }
  };

  //catch enter
  $(".tags-area").on("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();

          tagged(event.target);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Only the value for that item's input should be the tags entered. So the first item should only have: alpha beta gamma and the second one has: new two three

Comment: Updated to include the initial load